# Twilio WhatsApp list-picker

Tags: twilio

I have been able to create templates within my Twilio dashboard to include:

1. 3 "quick reply" buttons
2. 2 CTA buttons
   And these work fine within my flows however, I now need to create a template message which contains more that 3 optional interactive buttons for my users to be able to select.

This is where the list-picker template option would be ideal.

My question is how can I create a list-picker (with more that 3 interactive buttons/selections) template message for use in my current Twilio Flows?

Any help with this one would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the whatsapp templates in the Twilio console don't offer this option.

But Twilio has a program called [Messaging Content API](https://www.twilio.com/go/messaging-content-api-request-access-1) that is in Private Beta, and with it you can submit all type of templates (CTA, Quickly Reply, Location, List Picker). To get access to it, please fill out the form above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I discovered after an extensive research both in Twilio and Meta (WhatsApp) docs.

As far as I understand, by the time I write this there is no way you can send a messages list outside the 24-hour window. But you can within the 24-hour window.

First we have to understand that there are two types of templates in Twilio, the WhatsApp Templates and the Content Templates.

- The WhatsApp Templates are for the messages you want to send outside the 24-hour window as a business-initiated conversation, these need to be approved by Meta and there are only two types:

1. Call-to-action: a text message with up to two buttons that open a url or phone number.
2. Quick reply: a text message with up to three buttons.

- The Content Templates are for the messages you want to send within the 24-hour window, these don't necessarily need to be approved by Meta and there are seven types:

1. Text: a text message.
2. Media: a text message with media attached to it, like images.
3. Quick reply: a text message with up to three buttons.
4. Call-to-action: a text message with up to two buttons that open a url or phone number.
5. List picker: a text message with a list of options attached to it.
6. Card: a text message with media attached to it with up to three buttons.
7. WhatsApp Authentication: a text message with a variable with a button to copy an authentication code.

To create a WhatsApp Template go to Develop -> Messaging -> Senders -> WhatsApp templates. Once you get it approved, you can send it with the language you prefer, using the "from" and "to" phone numbers, and the body of the message must match the body of your template.

To create a Content Template go to Develop -> Messaging -> Senders -> Content Editor -> Keep the Sid of your template. Additionally, you have to configure a Messaging Service, to do so, go to Develop -> Messaging -> Services -> Create Messaging Service -> Add Senders -> Link your WhatsApp Sender -> Keep the Sid of your Messaging Service. Now you can send it with the language you prefer, using the "to" phone number, the "from" Sid of your Messaging Service and the "content_sid" Sid of your Content Template.

Check the docs for more details:

[Using Buttons In WhatsApp](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/buttons)

[Send Templates Created with the Content Editor or Content API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/content/send-templates-created-with-the-content-editor)

[Send WhatsApp Notification Messages with Templates](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/send-whatsapp-notification-messages-templates)